# Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram by editing the number of labels

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, tensorboard, tensorflow-datasets

I have **decreased** the deflault number of labels from 19 to 10 of *dataset cityscapes*. My goal is to change the dataset so the decoder need to relearn the weights, as an preperation-exercise of **increasing** the output classes of the decoder.

The network I am using is [deeplab](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/deeplab/g3doc/cityscapes.md), the trainning process is fine at first. About 500 steps were run before the error.

(The code below doesn't start from the first line after the start of training)

```
I1111 16:19:23.461441 140502638323520 basic_session_run_hooks.py:692] global_step/sec: 1.82067
Total loss is :[6.42209053]
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.84064
I1111 16:19:28.894436 140502638323520 basic_session_run_hooks.py:692] global_step/sec: 1.84064
Total loss is :[6.23576546]
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.84368
I1111 16:19:34.318257 140502638323520 basic_session_run_hooks.py:692] global_step/sec: 1.84368
Total loss is :[6.09628582]
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.83645
I1111 16:19:39.763585 140502638323520 basic_session_run_hooks.py:692] global_step/sec: 1.83645
Total loss is :[6.20008707]
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1.84192
I1111 16:19:45.192930 140502638323520 basic_session_run_hooks.py:692] global_step/sec: 1.84192
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram for: image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1
     [[{{node image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1}}]]
     [[Mean_225/_10177]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram for: image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1
     [[{{node image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 521, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "/home/zwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "/home/zwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 515, in main
    sess.run([train_tensor])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 754, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1252, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1353, in run
    raise six.reraise(*original_exc_info)
  File "/home/zwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1338, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1411, in run
    run_metadata=run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/monitored_session.py", line 1169, in run
    return self._sess.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1173, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1350, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1370, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram for: image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1
     [[node image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1 (defined at home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py:328) ]]
     [[Mean_225/_10177]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram for: image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1
     [[node image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1 (defined at home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py:328) ]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1:
 image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read (defined at home/zwang/workspace/models-master/research/deeplab/model.py:478)

Input Source operations connected to node image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1:
 image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance/read (defined at home/zwang/workspace/models-master/research/deeplab/model.py:478)

Original stack trace for 'image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1':
  File "home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 521, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 40, in run
    _run(main=main, argv=argv, flags_parser=_parse_flags_tolerate_undef)
  File "home/zwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 299, in run
    _run_main(main, args)
  File "home/zwang/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/absl/app.py", line 250, in _run_main
    sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 472, in main
    dataset.ignore_label)
  File "home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 379, in _train_deeplab_model
    reuse_variable=(i != 0))
  File "home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 275, in _tower_loss
    _build_deeplab(iterator, {common.OUTPUT_TYPE: num_of_classes}, ignore_label)
  File "home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 257, in _build_deeplab
    output_type_dict[model.MERGED_LOGITS_SCOPE])
  File "home/zwang/workspace//models-master/research/deeplab/train.py", line 328, in _log_summaries
    tf.summary.histogram(model_var.op.name, model_var)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/summary/summary.py", line 179, in histogram
    tag=tag, values=values, name=scope)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_logging_ops.py", line 329, in histogram_summary
    "HistogramSummary", tag=tag, values=values, name=name)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 788, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 507, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3616, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2005, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()
```

I think the error

```
  (0) Invalid argument: Nan in summary histogram for: image_pooling/BatchNorm/moving_variance_1
```

seems like an error of tensorboard, is there some way to avoid it?

Since my training has run 500 steps out of 30000 steps without any problem. I am hoping that without some part of the function *(like histogram of tensorboard)*, or by editing the num_of_labels somewhere else _(maybe there is another parameter of the_num_of_classes may need editing)_, the trainning process would run properly.

Could you give some suggestions either direkt to this error, or to my general approach? Thanks

Best Regards

Zhe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved be adjusting the hyper-parameters for training, like decreasing the learning rate to stabilize the training process.

Comment: Can you explain what adjustments you had to make to solve this problem?

Comment: as I remember, I decreased the start-up learning rate. You could also try to use a pre-trained model in order to have a stable training process